# Node js, split up files without having to pass dependencies around?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, koa

This may be just me lacking a 'bigger picture' so to speak, but I'm having trouble understanding why exporting modules is needed to just split up files.
I tried doing something like this:

```
//server.js
var app = require('koa')();
var othermodule1 = require('othermodule1')();
var othermodule2 = require('othermodule2')();

var router = require('./config/routes')();
app.use(router.routes());




//routes.js
module.exports = require('koa-router')()
.get('*', function*(next){
    othermodule1.something;
})
```

realizing that routes.js does not have access to 'othermodule1' after calling it from serverjs. I know that there's a way to pass needed variables during the require call, but I have a lot more than just 2 modules that I would need to pass. So from my probably naive perspective, this seems somewhat unnecessarily cumbersome. Someone care to enlighten me or is there actually a way to do this that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each node.js module is meant to be a stand-alone sharable unit.  It includes everything that it needs to do its job.  That's the principle behind modules.

This principle makes for a little more overhead at the start of each module to `require()` in everything you need in that module, but it's only done once at the server startup and all modules are cached anyway so it isn't generally a meaningful performance issue.

You can make global things by assigning to the `global` object, but they that often breaks modularity and definitely goes against the design spirit of independently shareable modules.

---

In your specific code, if `routes` needs access to `othermodule1`, then it should just `require()` it in as needed.  That's how modules work.  `routes` should just include the things it needs.  Modules are cached so requiring it many times just gives every `require()` the same module handle from a cache.

---

This is an adjustment in thinking from other systems, but once you get use to it, you just do it and it's no big deal.  Either `require()` in what you need (the plain shareable module method) or pass something into a module on its constructor (the push method) or create `init()` methods so someone can initialize you properly or call some other module to get the things you need (the pull method).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So for my specific use-case with routes, is it fair to say this is useful if I happen to want to switch to express for some reason in my server.js while still wanting koa-routing?

Comment: @House3272 - I don't understand what "switching to Express" has to do with your question at all.  All my comments about modules apply no matter what node.js framework you are or aren't using.

Comment: Oh sorry. What you said makes total sense for node modules that one would install via npm. But for my own code (such as routes.js which is very specific to my one server) I can't see much value in being modularized as it won't be shared or anything. My first comment was me trying to see how it *would* be useful haha. I figured perhaps if I wanted to switch to express for some other part of my app while still using koa for the routing.

Comment: @House3272 - If you want the traditional model of concatenated files without each file being a module, you can just use a couple commands in a build system to concatenate a whole block of files into one giant file for when node.js actually executes the code and then not have to deal with any of this.  I think you'll be a bit surprised how much of your code could be reusable in other projects if you actually think in modules.  Of course, some code will be entirely application specific, but lots of code can be generic.  Modules also make nice testable units too.

Comment: And that pretty much answers everything I was confused about. Grazie! I shall try to think with modules in mind, buta just for curiosity's sake, where might one find more information about the build system commands you mentioned?

Comment: @House3272 - That depends upon what built tools you want to use.  They aren't part of node.js.  Folks building Javascript projects seem to like to use Gulp and Grunt, though there are many others.  You could even just use a few shell scripts.

Comment: Don't concatenate files on the server side. I don't understand that suggestion. Anyways, it seems cumbersome to repeat the same `require`s in every router file, but it isn't that bad. I had the same problem when I was new to Clojure and even wrote a macro that would import the same stuff in all my route modules. Eventually in both Clojure and Node I realized I wasn't solving a problem. As jfriend00 points out, it might feel cumbersome, but you end up with a system where each file has explicit dependencies. With routes, they're mostly the same core deps but they will vary a bit over time.